# what Orthogonal Matrix is to do with image processing?

Tags: image-processing, matrix

I am trying to map mathematics to image processing. I am very much beginner in Math. I read what is orthogonal matrix is from this link : http://people.revoledu.com/kardi/tutorial/LinearAlgebra/MatrixOrthogonal.html

How can i relate this orthogonal matrix to image processing,or any other application of this orthogonal.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't spend too much time thinking about it.  Nonetheless.

The main place where we see orthogonal matrices in graphics/image-processing is rotation matrices.  For example, if I want to rotate an image by `t` degrees, I would (conceptually) transform that image by the matrix

```
[  cos(t) , -sin(t) ]
[  sin(t) ,  cos(t) ]
```

Meaning I would take a point [ x, y ] in my image, and transform it by that matrix to obtain [ x', y' ], the new location of that point.  Were I to do this for every pixel in the image and place the new points on a blank canvas (that could fit them, obviously), I would see (roughly) the image rotated by `t` radians.

This is an example of an orthogonal matrix.  To 'undo' the operation, I transform with the inverse of the matrix.  But since this matrix is orthogonal, the inverse is just the transpose:

```
[  cos(t) , sin(t) ]
[ -sin(t) , cos(t) ]
```

If I applied that transform to my rotated image, I'd obtain the original (I'm glossing over details like filtering).  That matrix represents the inverse operation of rotating by `t` radians.  It is, in fact, a matrix for rotating by `-t` radians.

In this case it's actually very easy to see that: if you plug `-t` into the first matrix, since `sin` is an odd function and `cos` an even, you'll get exactly the transpose.

This is conceptually very simple compared to a general matrix inversion. We like orthogonal matrices because of that inverse-is-transpose property.

Just one practical example.

Comment: just do add, an orthogonal matrix `Q` preserves length and angles. meaning, during transformation, an object's size and relative angle between vectors remain the same.